# EXTJS assign function to variable and call it dynamically

Tags: javascript, controller, extjs4

In my controller, I have the following ref and one function that I call after clicking a button. Is it possible to construct a ref method and then call it? I just want in a single function to handle many cases and I want to avoid if statements (as it is required in the project. It is supposed to be generic)

The type will come as a parameter to the function.

```
     refs    : [{
        ref      : 'saleForm',
        selector : 'sale saleform'
     }],

         init: function () {    
            this.control({
                     'salesview #mybutton':{
                     click : this.onSaleClick 
                    }
            }); 
         },

    onSaleClick : function(){

       //this.getSaleForm().show();//works

       var type = "Sale";   
       var method = "get"+type+"Form()";    
       this.window = window;
       this.window[method]().show();        
   }
```

Comment: I'm confused... if `this.getSaleForm().show()` works, what's wrong with doing `var method = "get" + type + "Form"; this[method]().show();` ?  You don't want the parens in the method name because you're invoking it after you look it up, and I don't think it'll be a global method, as it's locally scoped to your class, so you don't want to use `window`.

Comment: It works the way you mention!

Comment: Then there's something you're not showing us, as `type` is a string variable in both your provided code and Lorenz Meyer's answer... unless `type` is some special reserved variable you have, but it shouldn't be if you're local scoping it.

Comment: Was just missing a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible without problems. Try something like this :

```
     init: function () {    
        this.control({
            'salesview #mybutton':{
                click : function(){
                    this.onGenericClick("Sale")
                }
             },
             scope: this
        }); 
     },

onGenericClick : function(type){
   var method = "get"+type+"Form()";    
   this.window = window;
   this.window[method]().show();        
}
```

You must define the scope of the listener to be able to refer to `this`. Here's the doc about [the listener object](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-addListener). Instead of passing the scope globally in `this.control`, you could pass it just for one event, like this:

```
this.control({
    'salesview #mybutton':{
        click: {
            fn: function(){
                this.onGenericClick("Sale")
            }, 
            scope: this
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: Seems to have the same result. I get ----Property 'getClientForm()' of object [object global] is not a function----  This line is wrong <<this.window[method]().show();>>. Anyway that's how I see it in other post, if you want to call the method